# How to "refresh" Tkinter window in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, reload

I'm trying to reload a Tkinter window in Python through a button, but I'm having trouble figuring it out. You see, it uses the `import random` and randomly generates words from lists and when you click the button, I want to set the labels to different words, almost like rolling dice but with words.

```
import random
from Tkinter import *          #don't import like this except for Tkinter
root = Tk() #create main window
root.title('Atarashi Sozo')
# Make and place a canvas widget for events and drawing
canvas = Canvas(root, height=600, width=600, relief=RAISED, bg='white')
canvas.grid() #Puts the canvas in the main Tk window

#Create lists
creature = ['is an Animal', 'is a Human', 'is an Artificial Intelligence', 
        'is an Alien', 'is a Mage','is a Reptillian','is a Shapeshifter',
        'is Undead', 'is a Scorpion Hedgehog', 'is an Angel', 'is a Demon']
element = ['controls lightning', 'controls fire', 'controls nature', 'controls water', 'controls mater', 
       'controls time', 'controls gravity', 'controls life', 'controls death', 'controls wind',
       'can bend any metal','controls the sun', 'controls the moon', 'controls love']
features = ['has wings', 'has markings', 'has large fangs', 'has claws', 'has a tail', 'has a weapon', 
        'has cybernetic parts', 'has wolf ears', 'has broken teeth', 'has a horn', 'has big ears',
        'has eyes with two colors', 'has a mp3']
wildcard = ['is cursed', 'is bewitched', 'has no soul', 'killed someone', 'just learned magic',
        'has no wifi', 'has unlimited memory', 'is poor', 'won the lottery', 'set the world on fire', 'visited another dimension']
colors = ['is primarily blue', 'is primarily grey', 'is primarily red', 'is primarily green', 'is primarily orange',
      'is secondarily blue', 'is secondarily grey', 'is secondarily red', 'is secondarily green', 'is seconarily orange',
      'is primarily black', 'is primarily purple', 'is secondarily purple', 'has all the colors of the rainbow']
handicap = ['is blind', 'is deaf', 'lost limbs', 'fears everything', 'has broken bones','has a small head','has an illness',
        'has amnesia', 'is allergic to almost everything', 'is deformed']
habitat = ['lives in cyberspace', 'lives in a desert', 'lives in the mountains', 'lives in a volcano', 'lives in grasslands',
        'lives on the moon', 'lives in space', 'lives on a deserted island', 'lives in a virtual world', 'lives in the underworld']
personality = ['is clingy', 'is depressed', 'is energetic', 'is angry', 'is kind', 'is a jerk', 'is goofy', 'is immature', 'is happy',
           'is insane']
profession = ['is a teacher', 'is an assassin', 'is a graphic designer', 'is a programmer', 'is a photographer', 'is a blacksmith',
          'is a bounty hunter', 'is an inventor', 'is a mage', 'is a monster hunter']
hobby = ['likes to cook', 'likes to draw and paint', 'likes to build things', 'likes to play games', 'likes to shop',
     'studies alchemy', 'likes to write', 'likes to make music', 'likes to design', 'likes sports']
#Sets categories to choose from
categoryList = [hobby,profession,personality,habitat,handicap,colors,wildcard,features,element]
#Removes category from list if it has been choosen to remove the possibility of duplicates
catOne = random.choice(categoryList)
if catOne in categoryList: categoryList.remove(catOne)
catTwo = random.choice(categoryList)
if catTwo in categoryList: categoryList.remove(catTwo)
catThree = random.choice(categoryList)
if catThree in categoryList: categoryList.remove(catThree)
#Chooses item from category choosen
itemOne = random.choice(catOne)
itemTwo = random.choice(catTwo)
itemThree = random.choice(catThree)

#Creates the main visual almost the same as Atarashi Sozo in App Inventor
Title_box = canvas.create_rectangle(500, 90, 100, 18, outline = 'purple',width = 10, fill = 'violet')
Title_text = canvas.create_text(300, 50, text='Your Character', font=('Impact', -50))
Display_box1 = canvas.create_rectangle(600, 200, 8, 125, outline = 'blue', width = 10, fill = 'sky blue')
Label1 = canvas.create_text(300, 160, text=random.choice(creature), font=('Impact', -30,), fill='red')
Display_box2 = canvas.create_rectangle(600, 300, 8, 225, outline = 'red', width = 10, fill = 'pink')
Label2 = canvas.create_text(300, 260, text=itemOne, font=('Impact', -30), fill='blue')
Display_box3 = canvas.create_rectangle(600, 400, 8, 325, outline = 'goldenrod', width = 10, fill = 'gold')
Label3 = canvas.create_text(300, 360, text=itemTwo, font=('Impact', -30), fill='chocolate4')
Display_box4 = canvas.create_rectangle(600, 500, 8, 425, outline = 'saddle brown', width = 10, fill = 'chocolate')
Label4 = canvas.create_text(300, 460, text=itemThree, font=('Impact', -30), fill='gold1')

#Create Button
class Outcomes(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master):
    Frame.__init__(self,master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()
    def create_widgets(self):
    self.button = Button(self, text = 'Generate Character')
    self.button['command'] = self.print_text
    self.button.grid()
    def print_text():
    print 
app = Outcomes(root)

# Enter event loop. This displays the GUI and starts listening for events.
# The program ends when you close the window.
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  The sample code is way too long.  Less than 20 lines is needed to illustrate the problem and solution.  Anyway, the button function should randomly reset the displayed values.  How to do that depends on the widget.  You never said what your exact problem is that keeps you from doing so.

Comment: Note: I am NOT suggesting that you erase code on your computer,  but that you start a new file aimed at learning one specific thing.  If you still have a question after trying the guideline above, then I suggest that you replace the code posted here with the new, shorter, more focused code.  I constantly write and test short snippet of code separate from the tkinter-based modules I work on.

Comment: You are saying you want to change contents of label after button click but there is no attempt in your code for that. Changing text of a label is trivial. There are tons of examples out there. Please, first look at those, try them, _then_ ask your question with [MCVE].

Comment: do you mean `self.button['text'] =  'new text'` ? Create small, working example code if you expect better answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) has method `itemconfig(item_id, option=new_value)` to change item options. ie.

```
canvas.itemconfig(creature_text, text=random.choice(creature))
```

Simple, working example

```
try:
    from Tkinter import * # Python 2
except:
    from tkinter import * # Python 3

import random

# --- functions ---

def change_creature():
    # change text in item
    canvas.itemconfig(creature_text, text=random.choice(creature))

# --- data ---

creature = [
    'is an Animal', 'is a Human', 'is an Artificial Intelligence', 
    'is an Alien', 'is a Mage','is a Reptillian','is a Shapeshifter',
    'is Undead', 'is a Scorpion Hedgehog', 'is an Angel', 'is a Demon'
]

# --- main ---

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, height=100, width=300)
canvas.grid()

# create empty item
creature_text = canvas.create_text(10, 10, anchor='nw')

# generate first text in item
change_creature()

# use button to call the same function    
button = Button(root, text='Generate Creature', command=change_creature)
button.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** More universal - using parameters in function

```
change_text(creature_text_1, creature)

command=lambda:change_text(creature_text_1, creature))
```

or using it directly (without own function)

```
canvas.itemconfig(creature_text_1, text=random.choice(creature))

command=lambda:canvas.itemconfig(creature_text_1, text=random.choice(creature))
```

Code:

```
try:
    from Tkinter import * # Python 2
except:    
    from tkinter import * # Python 3

import random

# --- functions ---

def change_text(item_id, all_text):
    # change text in item
    canvas.itemconfig(item_id, text=random.choice(all_text))

# --- data ---

creature = [
    'is an Animal', 'is a Human', 'is an Artificial Intelligence', 
    'is an Alien', 'is a Mage','is a Reptillian','is a Shapeshifter',
    'is Undead', 'is a Scorpion Hedgehog', 'is an Angel', 'is a Demon'
]

# --- main ---

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, height=100, width=300)
canvas.grid()

# create empty items
creature_text_1 = canvas.create_text(10, 10, anchor='nw')
creature_text_2 = canvas.create_text(10, 30, anchor='nw')

# generate first text in item
change_text(creature_text_1, creature)
# or directly 
canvas.itemconfig(creature_text_2, text=random.choice(creature))

# use buttons to call the same function    
button = Button(root, text='Generate Creature 1', command=lambda:change_text(creature_text_1, creature))
button.grid()

# or directly 
button = Button(root, text='Generate Creature 2', command=lambda:canvas.itemconfig(creature_text_2, text=random.choice(creature)))
button.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly. I'm still new to python so this is great knowledge for me. Thanks again for the help.